# Purpose of "lock ID" in custom ASP.NET session store example

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, session, concurrency, locking

At the risk of revealing my ignorance I confess that I am confused about the purpose of the `lock_id` and `locked` columns in the [custom ASP.NET session store](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178588(v=vs.100).aspx) example from Microsoft. I get that this schema is designed for consumption in a multi-threaded environment and by many applications, so it makes sense that the PK includes the session identifier as well as the application identifier, allowing applications to re-use session identifiers. What doesn't make sense is the fact that the `lock_id` does not appear to reference a foreign key constraint.

Since Microsoft didn't include much information about the nature and reasons for the `lock_id` I am led to assume that it is obvious. Intuitively, it makes sense that it would be useful to indicate whether a session is being handled by, say, a particular application server at a given time, but I don't see how this physically translates into the schema.

Any clarification is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, this answer is equal parts guess and knowledge.

guess:

The database schema is used by a class called `SessionStateStoreProvider`, or one of its subclasses. In particular, it defines a method called:

[GetItemExclusive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstatestoreproviderbase.getitemexclusive(v=vs.100).aspx)

Now, I don't know for sure that the parameters it takes in map directly to the columns stored in the schema (and I'm not saying it's aliens, but...).

knowledge:

As for what they are used for, the answer lies in your original question:

> I get that this schema is designed for consumption in a **multi-threaded**
>   environment and by many applications

Within a **single application**, there may be multiple threads serving the same session id (consider if you had one asp.net website that saw a single user load two pages simultaneously). The default behavior of .NET Session State is to lock the session id for one of those pages, and assigning a random lock id to it. When that page finished, it would release the lock and the next thread in line would grab it and assign a new lock id. Normally, this would all take place in memory, but if you are persisting the session state model to the database then it makes sense for the lock id to go as well. Support for this behavior is why lock id is required in addition to application id and session id.